# DVWA can not create a database?

Tags: mysql

```
$_DVWA[ 'db_server' ] = 'localhost';

$_DVWA[ 'db_database' ] = 'dvwa';

$_DVWA[ 'db_user' ] = 'root';

$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = 'redhat';
```

I try to setup database, but it shows:

> Could not connect to the database. Please check the config file.

The password is mysql password.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please elaborate what `DVWA` stands for, tag the question accordingly.

Comment: The error message appears to speak for itself. There is little we can help here. Apparently your database server is either not running or not accepting connections via network.